# To run weblogic server in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, weblogic

I'm starting weblogic server in cygwin,
I've added set DEBUG_OPTS = -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5152,server=y,suspend=y in startwls.sh file
and passed this DEBUG_OPTS when stating the weblogic server.

But the server does not stops to listen the port, I believe there is no effect of debug_opts.
Please help me out to figure this issue.

I'm researching this issue for past two days but no improvement.

Comment: Where are you adding DEBUG_OPTS?  On the command line or in startWeblogic.sh or startWeblogic.cmd?

Comment: DEBUG_OPTS = -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5152,server=y,suspend=y in sh file.  Adding DEBUG_OPTS as paramaeter in starting weblogic server

Answer (score 0):

First.  When you start up the server you should take note that the DEBUG_OPTS that you are setting are being picked up.  I don't believe DEBUG_OPTS is supported by the weblogic scripts.

But are you calling **export DEBUG_OPTS** in your shell script?

In ALSB 2.6 you should take a look at bin/setDomainEnv.sh.  The default debug port is 8453 and debug settings will be used if you have debugFlag set to true.  See line 300.  You could also edit setDomainEnv.sh and put your settings in JAVA_DEBUG on line 297.

OSB works the same but the line numbers in setDomainEnv.sh are different (i.e 411 and 414).